# Подключение jar-файла

Tags: java, jar

Я собираюсь подключить JNA для использования внешних методов. Как это можно осуществить без использования средств IDE?

```
javac -cp lib\*; Sample.java
java -cp lib\*; Sample
```

Где папка lib содержит jar библиотеку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам необходимо при запуске вашего `.class` файла указывать `classpath`, эдакие пути, по которым будет производиться поиск сторонних библиотек (вы можете использовать сколько угодно библиотек, разделяйте пути точкой с запятой (`;`))

Например:

```
java -cp "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\deploy.jar" ВашКласс
```

Comment: Добавил своё решение к вопросу

Comment: Но аргумент -cp нужно добавить также и к javac